# Flash like SVG Animator Tool for Mobile?

Tags: android, video, drawing, animation, svg

For the desktop, I know there are many tools that can do exactly this such as...
[Animatron](https://www.animatron.com/), [Synfig Studio](http://www.synfig.org/cms/) with [this plugin](http://wiki.synfig.org/Sif2svg), [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/), and even [Blender](http://blender.org/)

Basically, I'm looking for a similar tool like say [Animatron](https://www.animatron.com/) for Android (However, it can also be for iOS as well).

- I'd like to be able to add/draw shapes/lines/text to the canvas
- Change shape's colors
- Add effects (Gradients, blurs, opacity, etc:)
- Animate the shapes/lines
- Group/Ungroup shapes
- Export as Video

Edit: [AlternativeTo](https://www.animatron.com/) is a great resource to find free alternatives to software (Just doesn't currently have one I'm looking for). I get it creating an animation tool for mobile is easier said than done. However being 2018 I'm sure there's one out there I haven't found yet or isn't well discovered.